# How to set bold rows while exporting to excel file.?

Tags: php, controller, phpexcel, export-to-excel, maatwebsite-excel

I want to set bold rows(a1 to m1) while exporting excel file ..
I have tried.

```
"$excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:M1')->getFont()->setBold(true);"
```

but it gives error.
This is my code.

```
Excel::create('Individual_data', function($excel) use($Indivudual_array) {
        $excel->setTitle('Individual_data');
        $excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:M1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $excel->sheet('Individual_data', function($sheet)use($Indivudual_array) {
            $sheet->fromArray($Indivudual_array, null, 'A1', false, false);
        });
    })->download('xlsx');
```

While exporting excel file...this is error---

> "Your requested sheet index: 0 is out of bounds. The actual number of
>   sheets is 0" this error.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm new to **PhpSpreadsheet** but I can share what I did and got the error away.

1. Make sure the excel file **is not locked or read only**
2. Ensure that the file is **saved as the default excel(xlsx)** not saved as Strict Open XML Spreadsheet(xlsx)